# Find all $f$ such that $f(xy+f(x))=f(f(x)f(y))+x, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that
> $$
> f(xy+f(x))=f(f(x)f(y))+x, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}
> $$

If someone can give me a hint for this question I would be very grateful.

edit: We can see that $f$ is injective because: $f(x)=f(y)$ then the equation above tell's that $x=y$.

Comment: By $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ you mean $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ right?

Comment: Please show your work/attempt towards solving the problem - this would help you get better answers.

Comment: (1) The identity function —$f(x)=x$—solves the functional equation; (2) Any other solution must be injective. What can you possibly say about other solutions?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_{>0}=(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Same question on AOPS: [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1952355p13478898).